# Spring 4 LTW not compatible with 64 bit JVM and Tomcat

Tags: spring, tomcat, load-time-weaving, spring-4

As part of moving to Java 8 and in honor of Spring 4, I thought I'd upgrade to all 64 bit code. This application runs perfectly on 32 bit but load time weaving does not work (in fact doesn't even load) on 64 bit.

Specifics of the architecture:

- Java 8.0.5 (32 or 64 bit as appropriate)
- Tomcat 7.0.54 (32 or 64 bit as appropriate)
- Spring 4.0.5
- Eclipselink 2.5.1

Testing under Spring Tool Suite 3.5.1 on windows.
Deployment Target RHEL

JVM startup:

```
-javaagent:C:\Users\...\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-instrument\4.0.5.RELEASE\spring-instrument-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar
```

The offending Bean:

```
@Bean()
public LoadTimeWeaver loadTimeWeaver() {
    return new org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver();
}
```

The error is pretty straightforward:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean 
with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource com/xxxx/config/DataContextConfig.class]: 
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Must start with Java agent to use InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver. See Spring documentation.
```

All I did was change to 64 bit JVM and use the 64 bit Tomcat container.  Very many hours of Googling and trying different versions and agents have completely failed to turn up any solution.  Any thoughts appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

It is a standard Eclipse Server config so I assume that basically means startup.sh start.  The addional JVM properteries are below.  Note that we are not deploying any AspectJ aspects at this time, that's the next release.  The results are identical with or without the AspectJ weaver specified.

```
-javaagent:C:\Users\XXXXXX\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-instrument\4.0.5.RELEASE\spring-instrument-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar
-javaagent:C:\Users\XXXXXX\.m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.8.0\aspectjweaver-1.8.0.jar
-Dcatalina.base="C:\Users\XXXXXX\apache-tomcat-7.0.54-64bit"
-Dcatalina.home="C:\Users\XXXXXX\apache-tomcat-7.0.54-64bit"
-Dwtp.deploy="C:\Users\XXXXXX\apache-tomcat-7.0.54-64bit\webapps"
-Djava.endorsed.dirs="C:\Users\XXXXXX\apache-tomcat-7.0.54-64bit\endorsed"
```

Stacktrace:

```
20140529 13:25:48,873 localhost-startStop-1 ERROR Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
    Error creating bean with name 'ieexbContextConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed;
    nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
        Could not autowire field: com.xxx.yyyy.domain.FlowController com.xxx.yyyy.config.IeexbContextConfig.flowController;
        nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
            Error creating bean with name 'FlowController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed;
            nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
                Could not autowire field: com.xxx.yyyy.repository.PendingQueueRepository com.xxx.yyyy.domain.FlowController.pendingQueueRepository;
                    nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
                        Error creating bean with name 'pend ingQueueRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#63244fdb' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityM anagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager';
                        nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
                            Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#63244fdb': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerF actory' while setting constructor argument;
                            nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
                                Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/xxx/yyyy/config/IeexbDataCont extConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed;
                                    nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Must start with Java agent to use InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver. See Spring documentation.
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4973)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1247)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1898)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.xxx.yyyy.domain.FlowController com.xxx.yyyy.config.IeexbContextConfig.flowController; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'FlowController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.xxx.yyyy.repository.PendingQueueRepository com.xxx.yyyy.domain.FlowController.pendingQueueRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pendingQueueRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#63244fdb' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#63244fdb': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/xxx/yyyy/config/IeexbDataContextConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Must start with Java agent to use InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver. See Spring documentation.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'FlowController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.xxx.yyyy.repository.PendingQueueRepository com.xxx.yyyy.domain.FlowController.pendingQueueRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pendingQueueRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#63244fdb' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#63244fdb': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/xxx/yyyy/config/IeexbDataContextConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Must start with Java agent to use InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver. See Spring documentation.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1017)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:960)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.xxx.yyyy.repository.PendingQueueRepository com.xxx.yyyy.domain.FlowController.pendingQueueRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pendingQueueRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#63244fdb' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#63244fdb': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/xxx/yyyy/config/IeexbDataContextConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Must start with Java agent to use InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver. See Spring documentation.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pendingQueueRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#63244fdb' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#63244fdb': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/xxx/yyyy/config/IeexbDataContextConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Must start with Java agent to use InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver. See Spring documentation.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:129)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1017)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:960)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#63244fdb': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/xxx/yyyy/config/IeexbDataContextConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Must start with Java agent to use InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver. See Spring documentation.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:632)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:442)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1094)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:989)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:276)
    ... 54 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/xxx/yyyy/config/IeexbDataContextConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Must start with Java agent to use InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver. See Spring documentation.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    ... 62 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Must start with Java agent to use InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver. See Spring documentation.
    at org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver.addTransformer(InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver.java:88)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo.addTransformer(SpringPersistenceUnitInfo.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:348)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:336)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
    ... 69 more
```

Comment: Full JVM command line and full stacktrace, please.

Comment: I have reformatted your update so the log and command line are a bit more readable. Please copy that stuff from log files next time, not from a console with inserted line breaks according to window width. Anyway, after having searched for possible reasons, I assume that you have a dependency version conflict somewhere here. It is hard to imagine that this is actually 64-bit related.

Comment: I like your formatting way better.  I will try pointing log4j at a file and see how that comes out.

While I was typing that I didn't see how it could be a version conflict I decided to go over the POM file one more time.  The only specific version I have in it is spring-data-jpa.  Inconveniently they march to their own version numbers.  The latest RELEASE is 1.5.1, which is what I specified.  However they do have a SNAPSHOT at 1.7.0.  By pulling in that it works with 64 bit.  So you were right!

Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ran into the same problem. But eventually the issue was not coming from spring-data-jpa but rather on Tomcat changes from 7.0.47 version (where everything is working) to 7.0.5x and tomcat 8.

Try removing spring-instrument.jar agent from your application WEB-INF/lib (and put a provided scope to this dependency if you're using Maven), this should resolve the issue.

I'm running a Spring 4.0.6 application with Eclipselink 2.5.2 and dynamic weaving with spring-data-jpa 1.6.2 on a Tomcat 8.0.9 server on Java 8, everything in 64 bits.
The 2 methods for weaving (agent at startup or spring-instrument.jar in Tomcat lib directory) are working.

Note: Make sure you are using aspectj 1.8.1 (comes with Spring 4.0.6)

Comment: THANKS Fred. It seems making the maven dependencies <provided> was very important. 

My working configuration in Tomcat 8 is:
1. Specify <provided> like Fred said for spring-instrument and aspectJ maven dependencies 
2. Copy spring-instrument and aspectJ jars into tomcat/lib
3. Specify -javaagent parameter for both those jars
As an aside with Tomcat 8 I had to move the ojdbc driver from User Entries into Bootstrap Entries.

Comment: OMG, you saved my day, spent whole day in debugging, change to provided scope solved my problem. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the current RELEASE of spring-data-jpa is 1.5.1.  That version is obviously not compatible with 64 bit - although it works fine with Spring 4 in 32 bit Java 8 and Tomcat.

The solution was to pull in the SNAPSHOT build of 1.7.0 which does work with Spring 4 and 64 bit. See 
[spring-data-jpa project site](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-jpa/) for dependency and official Repository POM elements. I'm not sure if I'll try to get SNAPSHOT code released to our production or not.  Hopefully they'll build a RELEASE soon.

It is worth noting that Eclipselink 2.5.1 is fully 64 bit ready.